# "Padding" break the size of width?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am learning to practise a basic responsive site.

I have 2 layouts (beneath each other) everything goes OK when I would like to add some padding of the upper layout (header). The padding breaks the size of width. And the page looks really ugly.

Please have a look at this code.

Here is the code `jsfiddle.net/01c6rtkm/1/` Please have a look. (Sorry, I just tried every tag with the link and Stackoverflow did not let me pass)

I need to add an padding about 10px to the #header without resizing the width and make the width in 100% all the time even responsive.

Comment: Add "box-sizing: border-box" in the same place you are adding your padding.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Or, use `calc(100% - 20px)` for the width if you don't want to set the box-sizing property.

Comment: By the way, w.r.t. your remark that SO doesn't let you post questions if you don't put the code in the question itself, ahem, why don't you put the code in the question itself?